# How to get expected and actual result on console when a test fails in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

Am newly trying postman test scripts for testing the API.
One thing which i am finding challenging is the expected and actual test result when a test fails. 
How should I achieve it.
I tried with console.log but it wont print if the test case failed.
How to achieve a more generic solution with a single function for all the tests.

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    console.log("TestCase: Status Code should be 200"+", 
        Expected: "+"Response code should be 200"+", Actual: "+pm.response.code);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That assertion error message is auto pushed to the test result section, if the test fails:

```
Status code is 200 | AssertionError: expected response to have status code 201 but got 200
```

You could use this but it would just be repeating what Postman tells you when a test fails:

```
pm.test(`Status code is 200 - Actual Status Code: ${pm.response.code}`, () => {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200)
})

Status code is 200 - Actual Status Code: 404 | AssertionError: expected response to have status code 200 but got 404
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont see the error message for my failed test anywhere in the results after i run my collection runner. Where should i check.I even exported the results as json but no error messages are displayed for the failed tests

Comment: You would see the test name with the `Actual Status Code` message within the Run Results UI page

Comment: Thanks, I added it as follows 
`pm.test("TestCase: Check Status Code, Expected: 200, Actual: "+pm.response.code, function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});`  but this is very common scenario, what if it more complex like checking for keys in response headers and also values in response nested deep. Doesnt postman have a build in way to write the actual result. I even saw newman CLI but even there i couldnt get.

Comment: I tried evaluation for true of false in expected, but the hasOwnProperty doesnt seem to work : `pm.test("TestCase: Check Content-Type is present, Expected: true, Actual: ", function () {
   console.log(pm.response.headers.hasOwnProperty("Content-Type"));
   pm.expect(pm.response).to.have.header("Content-Type");
});`

Comment: You're asking multiple different questions in the same question at the moment - What you're doing in the comments isn't the right place to do this...Raise a seperate question to completely capture the next problem that you are facing. If the answers provided have helped, then upvote or answer them and move on to the next question,

Answer (score 1):

In [Postman Sandbox API reference](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) you have a generic example for expecting status OK (200) from server:

```
pm.sendRequest('https://postman-echo.com/get', (err, res) => {    
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    pm.test('response should be okay to process', () => { 
        pm.expect(err).to.equal(null);
        pm.expect(res).to.have.property('code', 200);
        pm.expect(res).to.have.property('status', 'OK');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the example but how should i incorporate it as a generic method for all my tests. one example is as follows                                                          
      `pm.test("Match content of String", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.string).to.eql(data.string);
});`

Comment: you could add it to the collection or sub folder so you're not adding it to each request?

Comment: I also have dynamic tests where the data always comes from a json file. I am using the collection Runner of postman to simulate requests. So, am using the tests tab to just write test and no request is being sent. Even when the result fails in the run results section, i dont see assertion errors. How should i incorporate the above function in the following test: `pm.test("Content-Type is present", function () {
   pm.expect(pm.response).to.have.header("Content-Type");
});`